# How can I use Linguist in Qt without .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to translate my language to another arbitary language.

but in my case, i generated project by using vs2013->Qt5 project->Qt Application.

so i don't have ".pro" file or qmake.exe file.

but when i search about the method to use linguist tool, all of them says i have to use .pro file.

Is there any ways to use qt linguist tool without .pro file?

(I tried to make it by using exe file in QT 5.7.0, but it has failed to complie. )

if it is impossible, how can i create ".pro" file in current project?

please share your ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Qt project file is not necessary.  You can load your `.ts` files into Linguist, either from the File/Open menu item or as command-line arguments.

You'll want to run `lupdate` first, to generate initial TS files.  It's normally sufficient to pass your source directory as argument:

```sh
lupdate -recursive '.' -ts MyApp_en_US.ts
```

That will generate an empty translations file for US English which can now be edited in Linguist.

You can generate the QM compiled translations interactively from Linguist's menu; I prefer to produce it as part of my projects' build with a simple Make rule that invokes `qrelease`.

Comment: thanks for you reply. and i have some problems in making .ts file.

Comment: Many says i need .pro file to make .ts file. isn't it?

Comment: Does the `lupdate` invocation I showed not work for you?  It should accept source files or directories just as happily as project files.