# How to generate language file using linguist and lrelease

Tags: qt, translation, qt-linguist

I have some code in a proprietary language. Its specially generated to make "plugin-code" and formulars. The main program is developed in c++.

The code looks like

```
a$ = pm("Datum")
b$ = pm("Seite %1!", page$)
```

The first argument in the `pm()` function is the text to be translated. "%1"... should be replaced by the following arguments, that must be strings. "a$", "b$" and "page$" are string variables.

The handout says, to use this function, I need a "foreign language catalogue". To make this I have to use "linguist" and "lrelease".

I have installed (all version 5.12.3)

- linguist
- lrelease
- lpupdate

So how could I make language files?

I tried `lupdate -recursive '.' -ts HAUSMITTEIL_de.ts` [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213534/how-can-i-use-linguist-in-qt-without-pro-file) but get the message

```text
Scanning directory '.'...  
Updating 'HAUSMITTEIL_de.ts'...  
    Found 0 source text(s) (0 new and 0 already existing)
```

and a XML file HAUSMITTEIL_de.ts

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="de_DE">
</TS>
```

I miss the strings to be translated.

Comment: lupdate looks through files for Qt's translation functions (e.g. `tr()` or `qsTr()`). That's how it knows which strings need translations.

Comment: @JarMan - No chance of configuration? lupdate should find `pm()`. I think `tr()` is reserved to use it like `tr///` in perl. - Thanks so far!

Comment: I have no idea if it's possible to use it for things other than Qt source files. I doubt it though.